# Calculate Mean in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several textboxes in Word and I want to calculate the mean and print this mean in another textbox. The values are numeric.

My previous code is working fine, but only if no values get deleted or changed. Is there a more flexible mean function in VBA that always updates automatically if a textbox is changed?

Here is my previous code:

```
Private Sub TextBox71_Change()
TextBox81.Text = Round(((CDbl(TextBox11.Text) + CDbl(TextBox21.Text) + CDbl(TextBox31.Text)) / 3), 2)
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have each text box change event call the same Function That Function would do the calculation and output to box 81.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, I suspect you need fully referenced objects rather than just TextBox21 etc, but the idea I am laying out would look something like as follows; string for return type.

```
Private Sub TextBox11_Change()
    TextBox81.Text = CalculateMean
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Change()
    TextBox81.Text = CalculateMean
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox31_Change()
     TextBox81.Text = CalculateMean
End Sub

Public Function CalculateMean() As String

     If Len(TextBox11.Text) + Len(TextBox21.Text) + Len(TextBox31.Text) = 0 Then
        CalculateMean = vbNullString 'CalculateMean = "0"
     ElseIf TextBox11.Text = vbNullString Or TextBox21.Text = vbNullString Or TextBox31.Text = vbNullString Then
        CalculateMean = CStr(Round(((CDbl(IIf(TextBox11.Text = vbNullString, 0, TextBox11.Text)) + CDbl(IIf(TextBox21.Text = vbNullString, 0, TextBox21.Text)) + CDbl(IIf(TextBox31.Text = vbNullString, 0, TextBox31.Text))) / 2), 2))
     Else
       CalculateMean = CStr(Round(((CDbl(TextBox11.Text) + CDbl(TextBox21.Text) + CDbl(TextBox31.Text)) / 3), 2))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: The values are in fact numeric, sorry I forgot to mention it. You did a similar thing I tried before but both ways end up with the same error: Type mismatch (Error 13).

Comment: Did you return a string? My function was returning a string though I just change it to return a double. Did you try with my first version?

Comment: I tried with both versions and it did not work out. Same Error Type mismatch.

Comment: In the CalculateMean = Round... Line

Comment: hummmmmm....Text should expect a text string hence CStr(Round(((CDbl(TextBox11.Text) + CDbl(TextBox21.Text) + CDbl(TextBox31.Text)) / 3), 2)) and returning a string from the function.  Do you have a document you can share?

Comment: I think the problem is the following. When I fill up textbox 11 the other two are still empty and so the calculate mean function does not work as the values have a different type. This is why I was working for a more flexible mean function in VBA in the first place.

Comment: good point well made. You have hardcoded for three values though. So you want it to calculat for 1,2 or 3 values present?

Comment: Yes. The values are typed into the Word Document into single textboxes and the mean should be automatically calculated in a new textbox.

Comment: See very messy update but I am guessing you can see the principle applied. I can't test on this machine.

Comment: I made it work somehow with a combination of our ideas, adding the following lines for each private sub: `If Not (TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "") Then
    TextBox81.Text = CalculateMean
    Else: TextBox81.Text = "0"
End If`

Comment: vbNullString is more efficient than "". Also, the reason for my multiple conditions is you want to divide by the appropriate number.

Answer (score 0):

If you used formfields instead of ActiveX textboxes, the lot could be done without a single line of VBA code - which also means users wouldn't need to allow your macro to run. ActiveX also isn't supported on Macs.

To see how to do a wide range of other calculations in Word using field coding, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at:

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154369-Microsoft-Word-Field-Maths-Tutorial

or:

http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party